# Is there a BQP algorithm for each level of the polynomial hierarchy PH?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, bqp, forrelation

This question is inspired by thinking about quantum computing power with respect to [games](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/will-quantum-computers-be-able-to-solve-the-game-of-chess), such as chess/checkers/other toy games.  Games fit naturally into the polynomial hierarchy $\mathrm{PH}$; I'm curious about follow-up questions.

Every Venn diagram or Hasse diagram I see illustrating the "standard model" of computational complexity describes a universe of $\mathrm{PSPACE}$ problems, and puts $\mathrm{BQP}$ into a position containing all of $\mathrm{P}$, and not containing all of $\mathrm{NP}$, but *cutting through* to outside of the polynomial hierarchy $\mathrm{PH}$.  That is, such Venn diagrams posit that there are likely problems efficiently solvable with a quantum computer that are outside of $\mathrm{PH}$.

But how does this "cut through?"

That is, does this imply that there must be a $\mathrm{BQP}$ problem in the *first* level of the hierarchy, one in the *second* level of the hierarchy, one in the *third* level $\cdots$, and one such as "forrelation" (correlation of Fourier series) *completely outside* of the hierarchy?

Or could it be that there are some $\mathrm{BQP}$ problems in the *first* level of the hierarchy, some *outside* of the hierarchy, and an infinite number of levels of the hierarchy that are voided of any $\mathrm{BQP}$ problems?

[image: Quanta Magazine Article]

See, e.g., the above picture from the Quanta Magazine article "Finally, a Problem that Only Quantum Computers Will Ever Be Able to Solve" [link](https://www.quantamagazine.org/finally-a-problem-that-only-quantum-computers-will-ever-be-able-to-solve-20180621/).  Could $\mathrm{BQP}$ be disconnected between $\mathrm{NP}$ and the island outside of $\mathrm{PH}$?  Or must there be a bridge over $\mathrm{PH}$ connecting the two?

Comment: I find it quite a natural and interesting problem. Is it possible to make this post accessible to cs.theory.se? We can hope for an answer/pointer from them.

Comment: You're free to generalize the question and ask over there - you can point to this question here but otherwise it's generally bad form to forum shop and cross-post. If you do post a related question over on cstheory then I recommend changing the wording of the question to say something like "how does the Fourier hierarchy in BQP relate to the polynomial hierarchy PH" or something...

Comment: I will try the tips. Thanks!